# How to give filter out tags in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to generate a html from the following XML.

```
<students>
   <class action="update">2</class>
   <section action="update">B</class>
 <student>
     <name>ravi</name>
     <skill action="update">badminton</skill>
</student>
<student action="insert">
     <name>gauri</name>
     <skill>tennis</skill>
</student>
</students>
```

I am writing a xsl file for generation of the following table.

```
tag       subtag    action
class               update
section             update
ravi      skill     update
gauri               insert
```

My xsl file looks like this .

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
     <table>
      <tr>
        <th>tag</th>
        <th>subtag</th>
        <th>action</th>
      </tr>
     <xsl:for-each select="//*">
       <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@Action">   
       <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></td>
         <td></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Action"/></td>
       </tr>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>      
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
```

But this is generating the following table.

```
tag       subtag    action
class     update          
section   update          
skill     update          
student   insert
```

How can I handle the student tags separately. Please help. I am new to XSLT.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed, as you have `<section action="update">B</class>`. Neither is your XSLT, as you have a closing ` </xsl:when>` without a corresponding opening tag. Additionally you are missing the closing tag for the `<xsl:for-each>`. Can you correct these, to allow us to recreate your issue? Thank you!

Comment: @TimC thanks for pointing those out. Sorry for the inconvenience. I hope now the xsl is fine for recreating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this template instead as a starter

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
 <table>
     <tr>
        <th>tag</th>
        <th>subtag</th>
        <th>action</th>
     </tr>
     <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <tr>
           <td>
              <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test="name"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
           </td>
           <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="@action">
                 <td></td>
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="@action"/></td>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name(*[@action])"/></td>
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="*/@action"/></td>
              </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
        </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the solution.It works fine. But how can we handle cases where there are multiple changes for a tag.

Comment: It is hard to say because you have not shown this in your question, so I do not know what you expect the output to be in this case. You may need to ask a new question. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I will post a new question.